# How to properly add and remove JList selected values

Tags: java, swing, jlist

in Java, i  want to get the multiple selected values of a JLIst,

```
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    List myList = myJList.getSelectedValuesList();                  
    for ( Object L : myList ){
      listModel.addElement( L.toString() );
    }
    myJList.setModel(listModel);
```

it says a warning when i compile with Xlint:unchecked:

```
 unchecked call to setModel(ListModel<E>) as a member of the raw type JList
                myJList.setModel(listModel);
```

How to solve this? conversely how to properly remove JList multiselected items? (see below)

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new   DefaultListModel();
listModel = myJList.getModel();
for ( Object L : myJList.getSelectedValuesList()  ){
    listModel.remove( <some paramters > ); <---??? 
}
```

Comment: You might have to add the generic type information for the listModel and the jlist.

Answer (score 2):

you should replace

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
```

with

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
```

if you want to operate on String values.

if you want to remove element from list by its value you have to use

```
listModel.removeElement(value);
```

listModel.remove(int) works on indexes